# When and how is the map $ z\mapsto \int |x|^{-z}\phi(x)\ dx $ analytic?

Tags: real-analysis, complex-analysis, harmonic-analysis

In Wolff's [Lectures on Harmonic Analysis](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~ilaba/wolff/) (see also the AMS published version [here](https://bookstore.ams.org/ulect-29/)), the author claims without proofs in details the following:

> for $\phi\in\mathcal{S}(\mathbb{R}^n)$, where $\mathcal{S}$ denotes the [Schwartz space](https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Schwartz_space), the map
>   $$
> z\mapsto \int |x|^{-z}\phi(x)\ dx
> $$
>   is analytic in the "indicated regime", which may be done by using the dominated convergence theorem to justify complex differentiation under the integral sign.

I have the following questions:

- The "indicated regime" is not indicated in Wolff's [notes](http://www.math.ubc.ca/~ilaba/wolff/notes_march2002.pdf). Where should it be?
- in order to apply the dominated convergence theorem, it seems (doesn't it?) that one needs to estimate the integral
  $$
  \int \bigg||x|^{-z}\bigg|\cdot \bigg|\log |x|\bigg|\cdot |\phi(x)|\ dx.
  $$
  What dominated function should one use?

Answer (score 2, accepted):

The basic theorem is that $g(z) = \int_{\mathbb R^n} f(x,z)\; dx$ is analytic in $z \in U \subseteq \mathbb C$ if

1. $f(x,z)$ is analytic in $U$ for every $x\in \mathbb R^n$,
2. $f(x,z)$ is jointly measurable in $x$ and $z$,
3. $\int_{\mathbb R^n} |f(x,z)|\; dx$ is uniformly bounded on every compact subset of $U$.

Then we can use Fubini's theorem to say
if $\Gamma$ is any closed triangle in $U$, 
$$ \oint_\Gamma g(z)\; dz = \int_{\mathbb R^n} \oint_\Gamma f(x,z)\; dz\; dz = 0$$
and then Morera's theorem says $g(z)$ is analytic in $U$.

In your case, the only problem is the singularity of $|x|^{-z}$ at the origin: we have $$\left| |x|^{-z} \right| = |x|^{-\text{Re}\; z}$$
and we need $n-1 - \text{Re}\; z > -1$, i.e. $\text{Re}\; z < n$.

Comment: Thanks for your answer. I'm interested in a bit more details. While Fubini and Morera's theorems together are indeed handy (thanks for pointing that out!) I'm still curious about Wolff's argument using dominated convergence: how would you find a dominated function? Would you elaborate on why one (only) needs $n-1-\text{Re }z>-1$? I don't know how to use the decaying properties of the Schwartz function $\phi$ to get this inequality.

Comment: It doesn't have to do with the Schwartz function, just with the radial factor $r^{n-1} \; dr$ in the volume element of $\mathbb R^n$ and the fact that $\int_0^1 r^d \; dr$ converges iff $d > -1$.  The Schwartz function $\phi(x)$, since it goes to $0$ at $\infty$ faster than any polynomial, takes care of the integration over a neighbourhood of $\infty$.